# How to integrate the Piwik web statistics tracking system in a Drupal site?

Tags: javascript

Right now, I put the [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) code at the end of `html.tpl.php`.

How I can integrate it in a Drupal site, so that this JavaScript can be aggregated? Or better loaded and keep my template clean?

Can I put this code to an external JavaScript file (+ how?) and then just declare it at `theme.info`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even better, use the drupal module that does all the hard work - [Piwik Web Analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/piwik).

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... Adds the [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) web statistics tracking system to your website.
>
> The module allows you to add the following statistics features to your site:
>
> - Single/multi domain tracking
> - Selectively track/exclude certain users, roles and pages
> - Monitor what type of links are tracked (downloads, outgoing and mailto)
> - Monitor what files are downloaded from your pages
> - Cache the Piwik code on your local server for improved page loading times
> - Custom variables support with tokens (D7 only)
> - Custom code snippets
> - Site Search
> - Drupal messages tracking
> - Modal dialog tracking ([Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox))
> - Access denied (403) and Page not found (404) tracking
> - [User ID](http://piwik.org/docs/user-id/) tracking across devices
> - DoNotTrack support

Comment: thanks. In the past it did not have d7 version, so I didn't use it.